# Graph theory puzzle about connectivity?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, connectivity

You have a graph of **n** nodes (numbered 1-n) and **m** edges. You remove all the nodes one by one, and at each step you check if the graph is fully connected or not (by printing "connected" or not). The order of the nodes to be removed is given.

For example,

**n** = 4 and **m** = 3
The edges given are: 1 - 2, 2 - 3, 3 - 4. 
The removal order is: 3, 4, 1, 2

The nodes are numbered 1-n, so the nodes in this case are 1, 2, 3, 4.

Initially, the graph is connected, so you print out:

**Connected**

You first remove node 3. Now the graph is disconnected because node 4 is alone.

**Disconnected**

Then you remove node 4. Now the graph is composed of only nodes 1 and 2, which are connected.

**Connected**

Then you remove node 1. The graph is still considered connected; there is only one node.

**Connected**

Then you remove node 2. There is nothing left.

Sample code would be helpful, preferably java or c++. I tried using BFS and DFS, but they were too slow. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: To whomever is downvoting all of my questions: Why?

Comment: Stop copy/paste the problems someone asked you to solve, try to answer them, and if you can't show us where you failed. It's SO, not "We do your work".

Comment: I believe I have showed you where I failed. I said I used BFS and DFS, but they were too slow. I just want to know what the most efficient way of doing this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try working in reverse order.

Add the edges one by one and use a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to find when the set becomes connected.

Comment: Which data structure would you recommend? I'm coding in Java BTW

Comment: I've used the one described on the wikipedia page in the past and found it to be very effective.  It is only a few lines so should work in any language.